# sprite animation on key press

Tags: python, animation, sprite, pygame

I am trying to animate a spritesheet when you press a button on the keyboard.  My initial idea was to just blit the images on keypress.  I moved the animation code from the main loop to the user input loop.  That did not work because the game loop handles individual state for the entire game.  What technique is used to trigger animations from user input?  I want an animation system that can handle animations both by user input and also in the background on their own.

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "the game"
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

    images = load_sliced_sprites(100, 71, "spinning_roundhouse_kick.png")
    spritesheet = AnimatedSprite(images, 20)
    #while pygame.event.poll().type != KEYDOWN:
    while True:
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        event = pygame.event.poll()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #print "keydown"
            for image in images:
                screen.blit(image, (0,0))

        #time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        #spritesheet.update(time)
        #screen.blit(spritesheet.image, (0,0))

        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Looks like you're animating the same images over again at the same location. Are you supposed to be blitting the result of a `AnimatedSprite` object update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by tracking the frames of animation and using another while true loop.

```
import os
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def load_sliced_sprites(w, h, filename):
    '''
    Specs :
        Master can be any height.
        Sprites frames width must be the same width
        Master width must be len(frames)*frame.width
    Assuming you ressources directory is named "resources"
    '''
    images = []
    master_image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('resources', filename)).convert_alpha()

    master_width, master_height = master_image.get_size()
    for i in xrange(int(master_width/w)):
        images.append(master_image.subsurface((i*w,0,w,h)))
    return images



class AnimatedSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, images, fps = 10):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self._images = images

        # Track the time we started, and the time between updates.
        # Then we can figure out when we have to switch the image.
        self._start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self._delay = 1000 / fps
        self._last_update = 0
        self._frame = 0

        # Call update to set our first image.
        self.update(pygame.time.get_ticks())

    def update(self, t):
        # Note that this doesn't work if it's been more that self._delay
        # time between calls to update(); we only update the image once
        # then, but it really should be updated twice.

        if t - self._last_update > self._delay:
            self._frame += 1
            #if self._frame >= len(self._images): self._frame = 0
            if self._frame < len(self._images):
                self.image = self._images[self._frame]
                self._last_update = t

    def getimage(self):
        return self.image

    def isfinished(self):
        if self._frame == len(self._images):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def reset(self):
        if self._frame >= len(self._images): self._frame = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "the game"
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

    images = load_sliced_sprites(100, 71, "spinning_roundhouse_kick.png")
    sprite = AnimatedSprite(images, 20)
    #while pygame.event.poll().type != KEYDOWN:
    while True:
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_a:
            #print "keydown"
            #for image in images:
            while True:
                #print "frame"
                #print sprite._frame
                #print sprite.isfinished()
                time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                sprite.update(time)
                screen.blit(sprite.getimage(), (0,0))
                pygame.display.update()
                #sprite.reset()
                if sprite.isfinished() == True:
                    sprite.reset()
                    break

        #time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        #sprite.update(time)
        #screen.blit(sprite.image, (0,0))

        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you should be doing something like this..

```
sprite = AnimatedSprite(images, 20)
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        sprite.update(pygame.time.get_ticks())
        screen.blit(sprite.getimage())
```

What should happen, is your sprite class should get an update with the time delta, and count time before changing to a new frame. Draw your animation whenever the key is down.

Comment: I made the change and it looks like it is only drawing the last frame.

Comment: Each button press draws one frame of animation.